# How to group by one column, arrange each group, then order by another column?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a bunch of food nutrients. Think nutrition table on food packaging. Some nutrients contain x grams, some x mg, some x ug.  Grams are going to be a bigger weight than than mg, which is bigger than ug.  I want to order by greatest nutrient weight.

Here's an example data set:
[image]

So I imagine I have to group by unit_name, somehow order them like g > mg > ug, then order each group by amount.

Can anybody help me figure out how to do that?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: What about non-mass units? I see you have `kcal` and `IU` there - how would you define a sort-order for those when sorted with mass units?

Comment: Why do your `nutrient_id` and `id` columns have the same values?

Comment: Please use text tables in preference to images (my network blocks stack.imgur) so I cannot see your image.  sites such as https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ will form text tables

Comment: @Dai - mysql  Ver 8.0.23 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Comment: @Dai - I haven't decided how to handle those two yet.  But if I know how to do the others, I will figure it ou.

Comment: @PaulMaxwell - Before I did a screenshot, I tried pasting the ascii table directly from the terminal into the post, but it made a mess.  I just tried your link but it also made a mess.

Comment: @Dai - two tables are joined by nutrient_id and id.  Here's the query: select myfood_nutrient.*,nutrient.name,nutrient.unit_name
from myfood_nutrient 
join nutrient on myfood_nutrient.nutrient_id=nutrient.id 
where myfood_nutrient.food_id = 1921590
order by amount;

Comment: @Dai the ascii table generator allows you to specify what character is the delimiter, yours is the Pipe `|` and because rows 1 and 3 are already rows of dashes, remove those. Plus, even if you considered the original a mess it would be preferable to an unnecessary use of an image. btw: Here won't be the only time someone asks you not to use images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this approach:

```
ORDER BY
    case 
        when unit_name = 'g' then 1
        when unit_name = 'mg' then 2
        when unit_name = 'ug' then 3
        when unit_name = 'kcal' then 4
        when unit_name = 'IU' then 5
        else 6
    end
    , amount DESC
```

nb: you can tweak the case expression result to suit your intended priorities, mine is a guess.